# SSH Dependant session - Python Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Wondering if anyone has done it , or am I to descover the hot water here. The below script is my base for executing commands ( for now on one device cause I don`t know how to pass multiple ) , but I need to make it a dependant session . Essentially I have a jump host through which the SSH to my end device should occur . SSH to jump host, and from it SSH to end device(s). Ideas?

```
#Importing modules
import paramiko
import sys
import time

#setting parameters like host IP, username, passwd and number of iterations to gather cmds
HOST = "1.1.1.1"
USER = "admin"
PASS = "passwd"
ITERATION = 3

#A function that logins and execute commands
def fn():
  client1=paramiko.SSHClient()
  #Add missing client key
  client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  #connect to switch
  client1.connect(HOST,username=USER,password=PASS)
  print "SSH connection to %s established" %HOST
  #Gather commands and read the output from stdout
  stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command('show version\n')
  print stdout.read()
  stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command('show alarms | no-more\n')
  print stdout.read()
  stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command( 'show processes memory | no-more\n')
  print stdout.read()
  client1.close()
  print "Logged out of device %s" %HOST

#for loop to call above fn x times. Here x is set to 3
for x in xrange(ITERATION):
  fn()
  print "%s Iteration/s completed" %(x+1)
  print "********"
  time.sleep(5) #sleep for 5 seconds
```